# Convex Hull algorithm.

Tags: trigonometry, convex-analysis

Working on making a `Convex Hull` algorithm. I need to figure out how to iterate the remaining points to find the shortest angle as marked below in the picture. I am not very good with trigonometry - though I have been trying to learn online, just not finding an example of this angle because I don't understand how to get the sides based on a coordinate points reference system. I can find the bottom most point and start working counter-clock-wise from there. I will be doing this in a programming language (.Net) so I am looking for the math for the angles.

> [Research for Convex Hull](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/16Geometric.pdf)

Thanks for some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Even given your picture, it's not entirely clear what you are asking for. If this is an incremental algorithm for computing convex hull, please define what you want in terms of the current vertices/sides of the convex hull and the remaining points that have not yet been added to the convex hull.

Comment: In this picture it is not picking any points inside this finished polygon. So the bottom right angle was the first angle that was the smallest when checking remaining points, then continuing `ccw`

Comment: @user2566092 if you check the link I posted it should help you understand what I am doing - there are some great illustrations in there. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking the previous line segment as a vector, and comparing it against a vector from the end point to the other remaining points.

I have a program that does this, the output is similar to:

[image: convex hull image]

The code finds the point with the smallest y coordinate (in red). This is definitely in the convex hull, as are the left-most, right-most and base-y points. We go counter-clockwise, and to begin with we create an initial vector from the red point going east. Then we test each vector from the red point to every other point, and find the angle between the two vectors. The smallest angle gives the new line segment we want.

Then we use this new line segment as the 'control vector', and test for the angle between this vector and all the others (ignoring the red point).

My code is here:

> [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/convex-hull/5302471071236096)

but be warned, it's not fully functional yet! It works *most* of the time, it could potentially fail if the convex hull has too many points in it, and it stops halfway round, and starts again, because the 'heading()' function seems to get confused!

Comment: Thanks for that, but I cannot convert the code and it opens with > 100 errors in C#. What language is it?

Comment: I am really looking for the math from each point to test for the smallest angle based on the above drawing. Just not sure how to create a triangle of for new point by referencing the last so I can measure the angle.

Comment: @DonA; I think it's called KhanScript - it's very like JavaScript but has a useful draw() function which auto-updates at 30fps. The maths is there, use the dot product and/or the cross product - for two dimensions this is easy.

Comment: Ok, I don't think I will be able to convert it then. Do you know how I can project a triangle for each point left in the collection so as to measure the inner angle?

Comment: Finally found some code that will convert: [Convex Hull Algorithm](http://geomalgorithms.com/a10-_hull-1.html)